# Is there a reason to subtract zero from a number in Python?

Tags: python, math

I recently came across [this Python code](https://github.com/RazerM/orbital/blob/0.7.0/orbital/utilities.py#L269), here is a code snippet:

```
if abs(i - 0) < SMALL_NUMBER:
    # For non-inclined orbits, raan is undefined;
    # set to zero by convention
```

What really confuses me is this part:

```
abs(i - 0)
```

Is there any legitimate reason to subtract zero from a number before passing it into `abs()`? There does not seem to be any mathematical reason, but perhaps there is some quirk in the language?

Comment: I would understand `i - 0.0` but here...

Comment: To be honest, I don't think there's any reason to do that other than an attempt at a type check.

Comment: Added code snippet. The code is from an orbital math library but the question isn't really related to orbital math, other than that and the link I can't really provide more context.

Comment: What is `i`? Maybe that will also give you a hint how `i - 0` differs from `i`.

Comment: `i` is defined from the return value of an `acos()` function.

Comment: Maybe try contacting the author on this. I can't think of a legit reason for this either.

Comment: `i - 0` for integers, floats (incl. NaN & Infinity), and complexes pretty much just returns `i`. Since `abs()` already type checks (it will error on, e.g., `None`), I suspect that this may have been something leftover from the author’s debugging of some issue. As noted, subtracting `0.0` would convert an integer to a float.

Comment: One reason might be that the author transliterated directly from the mathematical formula. The logic can be clearly reducible from the code. It might not have any effect on the result but a reader might find it clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can only guess, but this code

```
abs(i - 0)
```

is attempting to materialize a *distance* between `i` and `0`, like we would do

```
abs(x - y)
```

Besides that, subtracting/adding 0 doesn't change the value of a float (else it would mean that continuously adding 0 would make the number drift...)

Note that it has a cost CPU-wise:

```
>>> 
  6           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (abs)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (i)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)  <=== not optimized out
              9 BINARY_SUBTRACT                 <=== not optimized out
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: argree with you, maybe `0` just stands by a math significance.

Comment: I think the author is trying to articulate the concept "arbitrarily close to 0".

Comment: yes, probably. But it isnt free as the disassembly shows

Comment: I assume then that it would be a good idea to remove these from a performance perspective in addition to a "it's confusing" one?

Comment: tbh performance impact is probably very minor. But I would not write it like this :)